# How to Use Count as a Criteria in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have an existing table1 which contains "account", "tax_year" and other fields. I want to create a table2 with records from table1 when the frequency of CONCAT(account, tax_year) is 1 and meet the WHERE clause.

For instance, if table1 looks like below:

```
account year
aaa 2014
bbb 2016
bbb 2016
ddd 2014
ddd 2014
ddd 2015
```

Table2 should be:

```
account year
aaa 2014
ddd 2015
```

Here is my script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE table2 AS
SELECT 
    account::text, 
    tax_year::text,
    building_number,
    imprv_type,
    building_style_code,
    quality,
    quality_description,
    date_erected,
    yr_remodel,
    actual_area,
    heat_area,
    gross_area,
    CONCAT(account, tax_year) AS unq
FROM table1
WHERE imprv_type=1001 and date_erected>0 and date_erected IS NOT NULL and quality IS NOT NULL and quality_description IS NOT NULL and yr_remodel>0 and yr_remodel IS NOT NULL and heat_area>0 and heat_area IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY account, 
    tax_year,
    building_number,
    imprv_type,
    building_style_code,
    quality,
    quality_description,
    date_erected,
    yr_remodel,
    actual_area,
    heat_area,
    gross_area,
    unq
HAVING COUNT(unq)=1;
```

I've spent two days on it but still can't figure out how to make it right. Thank you ahead for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to use count of pairs `(account, tax_year)` in `table1`:

```
select account, tax_year
from table1
where imprv_type=1001 -- and many more...
group by account, tax_year
having count(*) = 1;
```

so you should try:

```
create table table2 as
select * 
from table1
where (account, tax_year) in (
    select account, tax_year
    from table1
    where imprv_type=1001 -- and many more...
    group by account, tax_year
    having count(*) = 1
    );
```

Comment: Thank you! There are 11,755,200 rows and 71 rows in my source table. The query has been running for 20 hours and still is running. Is it common to take so long to analyze this size of dataset? I'm new to Postgres

Comment: The query is quite expensive indeed. It is very likely that the server ran out of RAM, which results in memory swapping. With the size of the table one should use special methods, eg. execution in stages by dividing the data into smaller logical parts using where clause.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT() = 1` is equivalent to `NOT EXISTS(another with the same key fields)`:

```
SELECT 
    account, tax_year
    -- ... maybe more fields  ...
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM table1 nx
    WHERE nx.account = t1.account  -- same key field(s)
    AND nx.tax_year = t1.tax_year
    AND nx.ctid <> t1.ctid         -- but a different row!
    );
```

Note: I replaced the `COUNT(CONCAT(account, tax_year)` concatenation of key fields by a composite match key.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I think your query will return all the unique records, not only just the records with frequency ("account" & "tax_year")=1. Use the table1 in my question as an example, the NOT EXISTS will return aaa 2014, bbb 2016, ddd 2014, ddd 2015. But what I really need is just aaa 2014 and ddd2015

Comment: You can add the extra conditions to the where clause (Note: you do **not** need GROUP BY, since you don't use aggregate functions with this method)